# Show/hide a div if the cursor is hovering over a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
if ($('.add-to-cart').hasClass("disabled"))
{
    if ($('.tooltip').hasClass("show"))
    {

        $(this).mouseout(function(){
            $('.tooltip').removeClass('show');
        });
    }
    else
    {

        $(this).mouseover(function(){
            $('.tooltip').addClass('show');
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purchase">
    <span class="tooltip">This is some information for our tooltip.</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" class="add-to-cart disabled" id="submit-table" />
</div>
```

I have found some solutions for my issue but none of them seem to be working for me.

I'm trying to show a `span` when you hover over a button and I'd like to also hide the `span` when you are *NOT* hovering over the button. A simple hide/show feature that I'd like implemented only when the button has a class of `disabled`, here's the JS that only shows the span but doesn't hide it.

Comment: Try using `.hover` to `.toggleClass` on your tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.hover()` which takes two parameters - one to run when you start hovering, and one to run when you stop. Pass it the function to show your tooltip and then the function to hide it and you should be sorted.

The general gist is `$button.hover(showTooltip, hideTooltip)`. You could write anonymous functions in there if you prefer.

I've done a quick jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/fv6ar05k/1/) demonstrating this with your HTML. I swapped the tooltip and button so that the tooltip didn't push the button out the way.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#submit-table').mouseover(function() {
  $('.tooltip').toggle('slow');
});

$('#submit-table1').mouseover(function() {
  $("#submit-table1").attr('title', 'This is the hover-over text');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="purchase">
  <span class="tooltip">This is some information for our tooltip.</span>
  <input type="button" value="Add to basket" class="add-to-cart disabled" id="submit-table" />


  <input type="button" value="Add to basket 1" class="add-to-cart disabled" id="submit-table1" />
</div>
```

try like this. Using [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to show or hide the span if the button is hovered

Comment: Sorry no this isn't working quite how I'd like. Imagine trying to replicate a CSS hover but with Javascript. The tooltip only appears when hovering over the button

Comment: @egr103 i added another sample maybe this what you are referring to. If this what you are referring to you should have made it  clear in the question

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need javascript to achieve this.  Here is a pure css solution.  First, rearrange your markup so that the span is after the button, like so:

```
<div class="purchase">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to basket" class="add-to-cart disabled" id="submit-table"/>
    <span class="tooltip">This is some information for our tooltip.</span>
</div>
```

And then add the following CSS:

```
.tooltip {
  display:none;
}
.add-to-cart.disabled:hover+.tooltip {
  display:block
}
```

[Here is a fiddle showing it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/3ycypaxz/2/).

The "+" is the key point here - this is the "next sibling" selector.  So the css selector is looking for a class of "tooltip" on an element that is immediately after an element that is in the hover state and has both the "add-to-cart" and "disabled" classes.

You can also use the "~" selector instead of the "+" to look for any element that follows the button, but is not necessarily the very next sibling (it still has to be a sibling, however).  Both selectors are supported in all modern browsers.

Comment: I like this solution a lot and in any other circumstance I would use it, however I noticed after some testing that a 3rd party plugin basically stops me from utilising this answer as it injects its own CSS between these couple of elements.

Comment: What does it inject?  I'm sure there's a way to overcome it without resorting to JS ;)

Comment: Incidentally, if you mean that the third party plugin inserts HTML between the two elements (thus preventing the "+" selector from working), my answer explains an alternative using the "~" selector that should work.  If it truly is adding CSS that is screwing things up, you can always resort to the "!important" keyword to force your styles to take precedent, even over inline styles.  The only time this wouldn't work is if the two are no longer siblings.  Even then, it may be possible to fix with CSS only.